# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'activeElement' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, google-places-api

```
<input placeholder="Search Box" v-model="origin" type="text">

mounted(){
var input = this.origin;
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
});
},
```

Is there something im missing?
I also added my api at my index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Please show us where this error be thrown. From you code snippet I have no idea where the **activeElement** is.

Comment: Where does the error come from?

Comment: Same error, the error shows up when I call the `addListener`